# Byobu available updates broken on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Tags: 10.04, aptitude, byobu

I noticed that since release of byobu 5.10 the available updates in the lower bar behaves funny:

- you issue for example an `apt-get update`
- available updates pop out with the `#!` in the lower bar
- `apt-get upgrade`
- the number doesn't disappear, unless the system is restarted
- if you the `apt-get update` again and new updates came out meanwhile the number won't change anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was actually a [bug](http://pad.lv/942469) in Byobu.  I actually just released a fix for that this morning with [Byobu 5.16](http://pad.lv/u/byobu).